# NodeJs and nodemailer - hide query parameters in the Email-Link and URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I hide the query-string parameters in the URL when sending an email to user with link and be able in the same time to read grab them when page is loaded in the browser?

Using: NodeJs, Angular1, MongoDb.

Code:

```
exports.newPass = function (req, res) {
User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email
}, function (err, email) {
    console.log('Email: ' + email);
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!email) {
        console.log('Email: ' + email);
        return res.json({ message: 'This Email does not exist!' });

    }

    var transport = mailer.createTransport({
        host:'localhost',
        port: 25,
        secure: false,
        auth: {
            user: "userName",
            pass: "passWord"
        }
    });

    var mail = {
        from: "DevOps <dev@localhost>",
        to: "dev@localhost",
        subject: "Set New Password",
        text: "To set new Password: ",
        html: '<strong>To set new Password: </strong>'
            + ' <a href="http://localhost:4000/endPoint#!/signup?m='
            + email.email
            + '&fn='
            + email.fullName
            + '&_id='
            + email._id
            + '">Restore Password</a>'
    }

    transport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log( 'Server Error: ' + error );
        }else{
            console.log( 'Message sent: ' + JSON.stringify(response.messageId) );
        }
        transport.close();
    });
    return res.json({ Ok: 'New Password will be send to you... please check your Emails' });
});
};
```

I'm able to manage this in the Angular Controller by adding the following:

```
$location.search({});
```

but the parameters and the values are still visible in the email-link.
They disappear after the user clicks on the email-link and goes to browser.
I would like to hide them also in the email which being sent to the recipient.

Comment: Why do you want to hide them?

Answer (score 1):

If safety is not a concern, you could create an object with the data you need, stringify it and then encode it in base 64. You can easily decode this back to the JSON string.

You'd do something like this in Node:

```
var data = { email: email.email, fn: email.fullName, _id: email._id };
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
var mail = {
        from: "DevOps <dev@localhost>",
        to: "dev@localhost",
        subject: "Set New Password",
        text: "To set new Password: ",
        html: '<strong>To set new Password: </strong>'
            + ' <a href="http://localhost:4000/endPoint#!/signup?d=' + data + '">Restore Password</a>'
    }
```

Note that anyone can decode this back.

Depending on where you want to get this data back, you'd have to check different ways on how to decode this data. It's pretty similar in Node:

```
Buffer.from(b64string, 'base64');
```

However, if you don't want people to be able to decode this, then you'd have to take a different approach.
What I would do is generate a random hash, and store it in the database somewhere, indicating that it's connected to some user that wants a password change. You can then send that hash to the user, and look it up when the URL you sent is requested.

Comment: Thanks, Yes, safety is an issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try